# UltraComboEditor (Infragistics) really slow

Tags: vb.net, performance, infragistics

So I have this UltraCompoEditor that takes very long to load, and the ammount of rows inside it is very large. Anyways I'm a complete beginer with Infragistics (I'm an intern) and my VB is iffy at best. Anyways I was hoping that someone here might be able to give me some suggestions or point me in the right direction on how to speed this up. This application was created and has been mainted by interns, I belive I am the 5th one, so the code is'nt great.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your question is too vague. How many rows are you attempting to load in the combo? Also, if you have a lot of rows, don't you think that your user will face difficult time to find a single item scrolling this combo? Perhaps you need a different approach to the problem and forget the combo.

Comment: If you run the query that retrieves the data outside of your application, how long does that take?  If that is what is taking a long time, then you need to focus on query or database performance issues--it may have nothing to do with VB or Infragistics at all.

Comment: You can also do performance profiling on the .NET application to see where time is being spent to see if it is your code or Infragistics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx